# How to use local shared library while compiling the FOSS project?

Tags: compiling, libraries, configure

I want to compile guile on shared hosting but when I run ./configure I've got error:

```
configure: error: GNU MP 4.1 or greater not found, see README
```

so I've downloaded GMP and tried to install it locally (found in answer to this question on Stack Overflow [install library in home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8944349/387194))

```
mkdir /home/jcubic/lib
./configure --prefix=/home/jcubic/
make
make install
```

it created this files in /home/jcubic/lib

```
libgmp.a
libgmp.la
libgmp.so
libgmp.so.10
libgmp.so.10.3.1
```

then I've run configure from guile directory (found the option by reading configure script):

```
./configure --with-libgmp-prefix=/home/jcubic
```

but the error remain, how can I use local GNU MP file while running guile ./configure and make?

Comment: Have you also tried to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` like described in the Stack Overflow post? You also might have to set the `CPATH` variable to `/home/<user>/include`.

Comment: I've called `
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/jcubic/lib/" CPATH="/home/jcubic/include/" ./configure --with-libgmp-prefix=/home/jcubic/` but got the same error.

Comment: Hm...not really sure, but you also might need `LIBRARY_PATH=/home/jcubic/lib` as well. If that does not work, try with the `configure` script environment variables `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: setting `LIBRARY_PATH` work now I have another library missing error, you can add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a sum up of the comments. One has to add the environment variables as follows.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/<user>/lib" LIBRARY_PATH="/home/<user>/lib" CPATH="/home/<user>/include"
```